# f# function to count number of digraphs in a string

Tags: f#

Im getting an error with this function. Im new to f# so I don't fully know what the code is doing, I tried duplicating a function that only takes one parameter to find vowels in a string.

```
let rec countDigraph c1 c2 L =
  match L with
  | [] -> 0
  | hd::tl when hd = c1 -> 1 + count c1 tl
  | hd::tl when tl = c2 -> 1 + count c2 tl
  | _::tl ->0 + countDigraph c1 c2 tl
```

gets called later in the code:

```
let printCountDigraph digraph L = 
    let c1 = List.head digraph
    let c2 = List.head digraph
    printfn "%A,%A: %A" c1 c2 (countDigraph c1 c2 L)

let digraphs = [['a';'i']; ['c';'h']; ['e';'a']; ['i';'e']; ['o';'u']; ['p';'h']; ['s';'h']; ['t';'h']; ['w';'h'];]
  List.iter (fun digraph -> printCountDigraph digraph L) digraphs
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

In `countDigraph`, you need to check that the first two characters of the list match the digraph. You seem to be trying to do this by first checking the first one (in the first case) and then the second one (in the second case), but this is not how pattern matching works.

The easiest option is to have a single clause that uses the pattern `l1::l2::tl` to extract the first two letters, followed by the rest of the list. You need to think whether e.g. `eai` counts as two digraphs or just one. If two, you need to recursively call `countDigraph` on `c2::tl` as below - if just one, you would recursively call `countDigraph` on just `tl`.

```
let rec countDigraph c1 c2 L =
  match L with
  | [] -> 0
  | l1::l2::tl when l1=c1 && l2=c2 -> 1 + countDigraph c1 c2 (c2::tl)
  | _::tl ->0 + countDigraph c1 c2 tl
```

The rest of the code gets much easier if you represent digraphs as a list of pairs, rather than a list of two-element lists:

```
let printCountDigraph (c1, c2) L = 
    printfn "%A,%A: %A" c1 c2 (countDigraph c1 c2 L)

let digraphs = [('a','i'); ('c','h'); ('e','a'); ('i','e'); 
  ('o','u'); ('p','h'); ('s','h'); ('t','h'); ('w','h')]
let L = List.ofSeq "chai"
List.iter (fun digraph -> printCountDigraph digraph L) digraphs
```